# What did Harry tell the snake at the Duelling Club in the movie?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

In the second movie, Harry Potter is seen communicating with the snake that Draco Malfoy conjured with the spell "Serpensortia!" in the duelling club. He communicates with the snake in Parseltongue, but does anybody know what he said, in English?

Answer (score 16):

### Something like "Leave him" or "leave him alone"

In the equivalent scene in the book, he says "Leave him alone" (emphasis mine):

> Harry wasn't sure what made him do it. He wasn't even aware of deciding to do it. All he knew was that his legs were carrying him forward as though he was on casters and that he had shouted stupidly at the snake, **"Leave him alone!"** And miraculously — inexplicably — the snake slumped to the floor
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* Chapter 11: "The Duelling Club"</sup>

Since the early films stuck quite close to the books (to the parts of it they didn't cut out, anyway), this seems like a plausible answer for the film as well.

It would, of course, be remiss of me not to point out that [a version of the script](https://www.gazette-du-sorcier.com/IMG/pdf/CoS_Script.pdf) (uploaded anonymously to the internet, so I can't vouch for its authenticity) has him saying "Leave him":

> Lockhart flicks his wand. BANG! The SNAKE flies into the air, HISSES in rage, and slithers straight towards Justin Finch-Fletchley. As students SCREAM, Harry -- oddly calm -- approaches the snake. It rises, fangs exposed, poised to strike Justin.
>
> **HARRY** (in Parseltongue) Leave him!
>
> The snake looks into Harry's eyes, then turns for Justin.
>
> **HARRY** (in Parseltongue) **LEAVE HIM!**
>
> The snake hovers a moment more, then -- miraculously -- slumps to the floor. Harry blinks, as if coming out of a trance, grins curiously at the snake, and offers his hand to Justin.
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* (2002)</sup>

Comment: Im almost certain he says this in the movie as well. I can't find any YT clip, but its after the incident and he tells Rom and Hermionie that he told the snake to leave him alone, but they said he was speaking Parseltongue. I only mention the movie, because OP mentioned it.

Comment: @MichaelPickett In the film he just speaks unintelligible Parsletongue.

Comment: @TheDarkLord There's a later scene where he says (in broad terms) that he told the snake not to attack

Comment: @The Dark Lord In that scene, yes. My comment referenced the following scene.

Comment: @MichaelPickett Can't be bothered to fire up the DVD, but it goes (as close as makes no difference), "... if I hadn't told that snake not to attack Justin..." Ron: "Oh that's what you said to it!" Harry: "You were there! You heard me!" Ron: "I heard you speaking Parseltongue - you know, snake language."

Comment: @Au101 Yes, thats the scene. Thanks.